# JAXB provider Eclipselink MOXy ignores @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` in `package-info.java` for `my.package` which means JAXB should care only about annotated elements. However, when I run my JUnit test with un/marshalling code for simple POJO MOXy just screams about every class (even from package without jaxb.properties or from other maven modules which are referenced in dependencies) in this manner:

```
Exception Description: The class other.maven.module.package.class requires a zero argument constructor or a specified factory method.  Note that non-static inner classes do not have zero argument constructors and are not supported.
```

I haven't encountered such issue with Metro (reference implementation, but it has other defects for my usage) and unfortunately I really can't modify every class in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to verify this issue, the following bug has been entered to track this issue.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/334681

**Issue summary:**

For the following object model:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class Bar {

    public Bar(String name) {
    }

}
```

The EclipseLink MOXy JAXB implementation is processing the Bar class although it should not be, because it is not mapped.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I hoped it's not a bug, just my mistake as I need it :)

Comment: We will have a fix soon.  Which version of EclipseLink are you using?

Comment: The fix has been checked in and can be obtained from the EclipseLink 2.3.0 nightly downloads starting tomorrow (January 20):  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: Hi Blaise, that snapshot had some other issues for me, but now it's working. However, I found some other problems which I've already reported in Bugzilla.

Comment: Hi Zdenek, we'll look into those.